# Show wordpress post in outside directory

Tags: wordpress, posts

My Site domain is for eg. www.demo.com i have installed wordpress in www.demo.com/blog now i want to show the all wordpress posts on my main site home page www.demo.com is it possible please help me

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common approach. It is well documented on the Wordpress site. Please see [Using a pre-existing subdirectory install](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory), it covers exactly your case:

> If you already have WordPress installed in its own folder (i.e. http://example.com/wordpress) then the steps are as follows: